# Difference betweek Kafka and Kafka Direct?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-directconsumer

Does any difference exist between kafka and kafka direct. If there's any, when should one be used instead of another and what will be the advantages?

Answer (score 1):

kafka direct is an optimisation which gives  better fault-tolerance guarantees and stronger reliability semantics overtime. 
park 1.2 introduced [Write Ahead Logs](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/01/15/improved-driver-fault-tolerance-and-zero-data-loss-in-spark-streaming.html). It ensures that no data received from any reliable data sources (i.e., transactional sources like Flume, Kafka, and Kinesis) will be lost due to failures (i.e., at-least-once semantics). Even for unreliable (i.e. non-transactional) sources like plain old sockets, it minimizes data loss. 
 refer to this [link](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html) for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

New **Direct API** for Kafka – This allows each Kafka record to be processed exactly once despite failures, without using Write Ahead Logs. This makes Spark Streaming + Kafka pipelines more efficient while providing stronger fault-tolerance guarantees.